# Address bar don't update in Safari 11 while I browse in YouTube

Tags: youtube, safari, address-bar

Safari is my regular browser. However, at some point (don't know exactly when), the address bar stopped updating when I browse in YouTube. It doesn't happen in ANY other website, only YouTube. And it only happens in Safari; I logged in in Google Chrome with the same Google account (in the same computer) and I could not reproduce that.

What I mean is: if I open YouTube and click in a video, the address bar keeps the value of 'https://www.youtube.com', not updating to the video page URL. The only way to show the video URL in the address bar is by opening the video in a new tab or window.

And it doesn't happen only when I start in the home page. If I open a YouTube video URL directly and click in one of the related videos, it keeps the URL of the first video in the address bar.

Switching between other tabs or window also did not help. There is a fix for that or it's a Safari bug and I have to report it to Apple?

Comment: There’s a preference for showing the full URL in the address bar. How do you have that set?

Comment: Yes. Also, like I said, the same occurs in the other side. I can see the full video URL if I open it directly, but if I go to other YouTube, like, let's say, the home page, the video URL keeps there, unchanged.